# Finding the possibility for oranges passing inspection, given that 4 distinct oranges are chosen from a box.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given a box of 20 oranges, anywhere from 0 to 2 of them are defective, with the likelihood of the defective numbers being equal. If 4 are chose at random from the box for inspection, what is the probability that all 4 oranges pass inspection?

I'm confused about how to approach this problem. If there is a range (0 to 2) being defective, how do I solve this? I can understand that for 0-2, all 4 oranges can still pass inspection, but I'm having issues enumerating the total cases in this space to calculate the probability.

Comment: The probability of $0,1,2$ defective oranges in the box of 20 are equal, i.e. all $1/3$. Can you figure out the probability of getting 4 non-defective oranges in each case? Then all you have to do is add them up and multiply by $1/3$.

Answer (score 0):

If $0$ oranges are defective, we need not worry.

If $1$ orange is defective, we need to find the number of ways we can pick $4$ oranges from $20$ without picking the defective one. Let us call this orange $1$, so that the problem becomes the number of ways we can pick $4$ oranges from $20$ without picking the number $1$.

The answer to this generically for $n$ objects, picking $k$ is:

$$\dfrac{k}{n}\dbinom{n}{k}$$

$\dbinom{n}{k}$ returns the number of arrangements. Each has $k$ letters. As the letters are equally distributed, we can divide by $n$.

So there are $\dfrac{4}{20}\dfrac{20.19.18.17}{4.3.2.1}=969$ ways in which we pick a defective orange.

For $2$ oranges, $\dfrac{k}{n}\dbinom{n}{k}$ gives both the number of arrangements that contain a $1$ and also say a defective $2$, but they overlap. We can solve this by considering just the set that contain a $1$. Each arrangement contains $k-1$ numbers that that we are interested in, and $\dfrac1{n-1}$ of these contain a $2$.

So the formula is:

$$\dfrac{k(k-1)}{n(n-1)}\dbinom{n}{k}$$

For example, if $n=8$ and $k=$ there are $21$ arrangements with a $1$ and $21$ arrangements with a $2$. $21\times\dfrac27=6$ contain both a $1$ and a $2$.

The rest of the question is fairly trivial.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this rather simply multiplying probabilities directly, viz. with $20, 19, 18$ ok,

$Pr = \dfrac13\left[1 + \dfrac{(19\cdot 18\cdot 17\cdot 16) +(18\cdot 17\cdot 16\cdot 15) + (17\cdot 16\cdot 15\cdot 14)}{20\cdot 19\cdot 18\cdot 17}\right]$